# MySQL: Why is DATEDIFF and TIMEDIFF/60.0/60.0/24.0 results different?

Tags: mysql, functions, date-format

I have a database with two DATETIME values, and then I generate some new values from them:

```
tdiff = timediff(d1,d2)+0
day1 = truncate(tdiff/60.0/60.0/24.0,0)
day2 = datediff(d1,d2)+0
```

All three of those "variables" are FLOAT fields in the (temporary) database. I would expect that `day1` and `day2` would never differ by more than 1 or 2. However, there are certain values that seem to generate a wild answer - and they tend to be for certain values of `tdiff`. Calculating the value from `tdiff` shows that the calculations are right.

Conceptually, day2 should be difference between the dates from the DATETIME values, and day1 should be the number of 24-hour periods in the same time frame.

The biggest differences are at the maximum value for timediff: using calculations, the number of 24-hour periods is just over 97. However, using the DATEDIFF function shows a time span of as low as 60 days. This makes no sense.

There are also big differences when TIMEDIFF results in 26 24-hour periods: DATEDIFF reports 10 days instead - or when TIMEDIFF results in 30 24-hour periods, and DATEDIFF reports 11 days. There are also differences when TIMEDIFF reports 79 days, but DATEDIFF gives 29 days.

Here is example output - from a Ruby script (and in Ruby array format) - with columns d1,d2,TIMEDIFF,24-hr periods,DATEDIFF:

```
["2012-04-11 06:15:21", "2012-02-09 22:11:21", "8.38596e+06", "97", "62"]
["2012-04-11 06:15:22", "2012-02-09 22:13:24", "8.38596e+06", "97", "62"]
["2012-04-11 06:15:25", "2012-02-09 22:15:29", "8.38596e+06", "97", "62"]
["2012-04-11 05:47:25", "2012-03-31 05:07:01", "2.64402e+06", "30", "11"]
["2012-04-11 05:47:26", "2012-03-31 05:09:03", "2.64382e+06", "30", "11"]
["2012-04-11 05:47:27", "2012-03-31 05:27:21", "2.64201e+06", "30", "11"]
["2012-04-11 05:48:43", "2012-01-27 16:39:32", "8.38596e+06", "97", "75"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:00", "2012-04-01 19:58:00", "2.2551e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:00", "2012-04-01 20:00:02", "2.25486e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:00", "2012-04-01 20:02:04", "2.25466e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:05", "2012-04-01 20:04:04", "2.2545e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:06", "2012-04-01 20:06:06", "2.2543e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:06", "2012-01-27 17:36:07", "8.38596e+06", "97", "75"]
["2012-04-11 05:49:07", "2012-04-01 20:08:10", "2.25406e+06", "26", "10"]
["2012-04-11 06:15:06", "2012-03-13 12:23:24", "6.89514e+06", "79", "29"]
["2012-04-11 06:15:07", "2012-03-13 12:25:25", "6.89494e+06", "79", "29"]
```

Why are these calculations so different? I am assuming that it is a lack of understanding of TIMEDIFF, but what am I missing?

Comment: the 2012-04-11 is 10 days after 2012-04-01. There are not 26 24-hour periods between a point int time at 20122-04-01 and a point in time at 2012-04-11.

Comment: True. But that's my question - why is it off? The calculation appears to be accurate `(x/60/60/24)` but the number of minutes (returned by TIMEDIFF) appears to be off quite badly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in fully understanding the `TIMEDIFF` function and what it returns as an integer.

First, let's consider `TIMEDIFF` in its native element and what it returns:

```
mysql> select timediff('0:0:0','1:0:0') as timediff;
+-----------+
| timediff  |
+-----------+
| -01:00:00 | 
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Second, what does `TIMEDIFF` return in an integer context - done by adding zero:

```
mysql> select timediff('0:0:0','1:0:0')+0 as timediff2;
+--------------+
| timediff2    |
+--------------+
| 10000.000000 | 
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Now, we use the `TIME_TO_SEC` function to return what we actually want:

```
mysql> select time_to_sec(timediff('0:0:0','1:0:0')+0)/60 as timediff3;
+-----------+
| timediff3 |
+-----------+
|   60.0000 | 
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The integer value returned by `TIMEDIFF` is not minutes or seconds, but rather a base-10 representation of the actual time - so 01:00:00 becomes 10000, and 05:05:01 becomes 50501.

Instead of using `TIME_TO_SEC` one can also use `TIMESTAMPDIFF` instead of `TIMEDIFF` and set the units to whatever is desired:

```
mysql> select timestampdiff(MINUTE,'2012-04-13 0:0:0','2012-04-13 1:0:0') as timediff4;
+-----------+
| timediff4 |
+-----------+
|        60 | 
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Instead of `MINUTE`, you can also use `FRAC_SECOND` (microseconds), `SECOND`, `MINUTE`, `HOUR`, `DAY`, `WEEK`, `MONTH`, `QUARTER`, or `YEAR`.

The time functions in MySQL (in this case, version 5.1) are all described in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html). The online manual also links to other versions (such as MySQL 5.5) as well.